# Может ли класс в c# кроме индексатора содержать ещё и какие-то поля?

Tags: c#, ооп

Появился вопрос, поскольку в примерах из интернета показываются случаи, когда в классе есть только индексатор. Если ответ на вопрос - да, то как это можно реализовать усовершенствовав следующий код так, чтобы в нем появился массив Marks:

```
class Student
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string Initials { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public int Salary { get; set; }

        public Student(string data)
        {
            string[] correctdata= data.Split(' ');
            FirstName = correctdata[0];
            Initials = correctdata[1];
            Year = Convert.ToInt32(correctdata[2]);
            Salary = Convert.ToInt32(correctdata[3]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Вот здесь нашел [пример](https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/csharp/csharp-indexer) с перегрузкой индексатора. Но если честно, кроме как в учебных целях, эти индексаторы ну почти никогда не нужны. Для решения таких задач есть обычные коллекции (например `List<T>`), словари `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, и есть цикл `foreach` и любимый Linq, чтобы со всем этим жить.

Comment: нет ограничений на поля в классе

Comment: вероятно ты смотрел примеры реализации индексатора, поэтому в них не было других полей

Comment: Начните с такого: `public List<Mark> Marks { get; set; }`